# Reconhecimento dos drives do SQL Server para conexão db no PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, sql-server, pdo, drive

Estou com problemas para me conectar ao banco de dados SQL Server.
Não consigo instalar os drives para ser reconhecido.
Na internet já tentei todo tipo de coisa e nada deu certo.
Baixei os drives no site da Microsoft, 
coloquei na pasta ext do php,
coloquei o código no php.ini para reconhecer os .dll e simplesmente não funciona!
Não aparece em phpinfo().

Comment: Habilitou TCP/IP do SQLSERVER

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: vc instalou o apache direto ou algum pacote como vertrigo, xampp?

Comment: Estou usando o Wamp.
Como eu estou iniciando agora com SQL Server, não sei se já esta habilitado ou não esse "TCP/IP".
Como posso habilitar caso não esteja habilitado?

Comment: Qual driver do SQL Server tentou instalar? da driver not found? qual é o erro?

Comment: Minha versão PHP é 5.6.25, a versão do PHP Extension Build é API20131226,TS,VC11.
Baixei os drives: php_pdo_sqlserver_56_ts e php_sqlserver_56_ts, coloquei os da versão 'nts' também pra vê se dava certo.
No php quando tento me conectar ao banco aparece o erro dizendo que falta o drive, e no phpinfo() não aparece essas extensões.

Comment: Você consegue montar um passo-a-passo do que você fez de forma que outras pessoas possam reproduzir o seu problema e/ou apontar passos errados ou faltando?